# How to find out the longest definition entry in an English dictionary text file?

Tags: dictionary, word-count

I asked over at the English Stack Exchange, ["What is the English word with the longest single definition?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358532/which-word-has-the-longest-dictionary-definition) The best answer they could give is that I would need a program that could figure out the longest entry in a (text) file listing dictionary definitions, by counting the amount of characters or words in a given entry, and then provide a list of the longest entries. I also asked at Superuser but they couldn't come up with an answer either, so I decided to give it a shot here.

I managed to find a dictionary file which converted to text has the following format:

> > a /a/ indefinite article (an before a vowel) 1 any, some, one (have a cookie). 2 one single thing (there’s not a store for miles). 3 per, for each (take this twice a day).
> >
> > aardvark /ard-vark/ n an African mammal with a long snout that feeds on ants.
> >
> > abacus /a-ba-kus, a-ba-kus/ n a counting frame with beads.

As you can see, each definition comes after the pronunciation (enclosed by slashes), and then either:

1) ends with a period, or

2) ends before an example (enclosed by parenthesis), or

3) follows a number and ends with a period or before an example, when a word has multiple definitions.

What I would need, then, is a function or program that can distinguish each definition (including considering multiple definitions of a single word as separate ones), then count the amount of characters and/or words within (ignoring the examples in parenthesis since that is not the proper definition), and finally provide a list of the longest definitions (I don't think I would need more than say, a top 20 or so to compare). If the file format was an issue, I can convert the file to PDF, EPUB, etc. with no problem. And, I guess ideally I would want to be able to choose between counting length by characters and by words, if it was possible.

How should I go to do this? I have little experience from programming classes I took a long time ago, but I think it's better to assume I know close to nothing about programming at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write code for you, but I'll help think the problem through. Pick the programming language you're most familiar with from long ago, and give it a whack. When you run in to problems, come back and ask for help.

I'd chop this task up into a bunch of subproblems:

1. Read the dictionary file from the filesystem.
2. Chunk the file up into discrete entries. If it's a text file like you show, most programming languages have a facility to easily iterate linewise through a file (i.e. take a line ending character or character sequence as the separator).
3. Filter bad entries: in your example, your lines appear separated by an empty line. As you iterate, you'll just drop those.
4. Use your human observation and judgement to look for strong patterns in the data that you can give communicate as firm rules -- this is one of the central activities of programming. You've already started identifying some patterns in your question, i.e.

   - All entries have a preamble with the pronounciation and part of speech.
   - A multiple definition entry will be interspersed with lone numerals.
   - Otherwise, a single definition just follows the preamble.
5. Write the rules you've invented into code. It'll go something like this: First find a way to lop off the word itself and the preamble. With the remainder, identify multiple-def entries by presence of lone numerals or whatever; if it's not, treat it as single-def.
6. For each entry, iterate over each of the one-or-more definitions you've identified.
7. Write a function that will count a definition either word-wise or character-wise. If word-wise, you'll probably tokenize based on whitespace. Counting the length of a string character-wise is trivial in most programming languages. Why not implement both!
8. Keep a data structure in memory as you iterate the file to track "longest". For each definition in each entry, after you apply the length calculation, you'll compare against the previous longest entry. If the new one is longer, you'll record this new leading word and its word count in your data structure. Comparing 'greater than' and storing a variable are fundamental in most programming languages, so while this is the real meat of your program, this shouldn't be hard.
9. Implement some way to display your results once iteration is done. This may be as simple as a `print` statement.
10. Finally, write the glue code that lets you execute the program easily. A program like this could easily be a command-line tool that takes one or two arguments (the path to the file to be analyzed, perhaps you pass your desired counting method 'character|word' as an argument too, since you implemented both). Different languages vary in how easy it is to create an executable to run from the command line, but most support it, so it's a good option for tasks like this.